# How to avoid rendering entire page when using CGridView via AJAX

Tags: yii

When creating any ajax request in yii CGridView like (pagination, filtering, ...etc) the result of request will render whole page, how can i avoid that?

I tried to use renderPartial for view but it doesn't work. if this is the solution, how can i do it?

I just need to render the table of GridView not whole page.

Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In controller:

```
$this->layout = false;
```

For me works also `$this->renderPartial()` in controller instead of `$this->render()`

```
if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest()) $this->renderPartial('view');
else $this->render('view');
```

U can create class:

```
class Controller extends CController {
    public function beforeAction($action) {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) $this->layout = false;
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
}
```